# Call UIActionSheet from UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subclass, uiactionsheet

i am making a form, in which a have en bunch of different UITableViewCells, with different functions, so instead of clutter my UITableView class with ode for every action, i wanted to implement each function onto the cells subclass itself.

So, i have a cell right now, where a UIActionSheet pops up, but when i tap nothing happens, even though the delegate have been set.

Is my idea wrong and will an other way be better to do it? Here is some simple code.

```
import UIKit
class STypeCell: UITableViewCell, UIActionSheetDelegate {

    func chooseType() {
        var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
        let title: String = "Please choose a course"
        sheet.delegate = self
        sheet.title  = title
        sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
        sheet.addButtonWithTitle("A course")
        sheet.addButtonWithTitle("B course")
        sheet.addButtonWithTitle("C course")
        sheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0
        sheet.showInView(self.superview)
    }

    func actionSheet(sheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println("this never gets called")
    }

    func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, willDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println("this never gets called")
    }

    func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println("this never gets called")
    }
```

Comment: try to show action view in keywindow

Comment: You will need to add a button or some other touch event action to spawn your action sheet. Quick question though, are you re-using cells? If so, I suggest making a function to handle this request that's spawned from didSelectRowAtIndexPath on the view controller that has the table.

Comment: my tableview works perfectly fine, all i am showing is the subclass of one of my cells. In my didSelectRowAtIndexPath i check for the STypeCell class and if so, i call the function chooseType() on my cell, which shows the actionsheet but doesnt fire its delegate @thefredelement

Comment: I think you need to set the `delegate` in `override func awakeFromNib()` method in the `STypeCell` class and it should work, but the accepted answer is the preferred way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TableViewCell should not have that kind of logic in it in an [MVC Patterned framework as iOS is one](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1).

If you want to reuse that logic, than you should create a TableViewController (or ViewController) which you subclass instead.
In the TableView Delegate methods you would then call your actions.

Example:

```
class MySuperTableView: UITableViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate {

// [...]

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
  {
      self.chooseType()
  }

  func chooseType() {
      var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
      let title: String = "Please choose a course"
      sheet.delegate = self
      sheet.title  = title
      sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
      sheet.addButtonWithTitle("A course")
      sheet.addButtonWithTitle("B course")
      sheet.addButtonWithTitle("C course")
      sheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0
      sheet.showInView(self.view)
  }

  func actionSheet(sheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
      println("this never gets called")
  }

  func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, willDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
      println("this never gets called")
  }

  func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
      println("this never gets called")
  }

// [...]
}

class MyChildTableView: MySuperTableView {

// [...]

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
  {
      super.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
  }

// [...]

}

class MyOtherChildTableView: MySuperTableView {

// [...]

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
  {
      super.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
  }

// [...]

}
```

Of course more logic would help like: What kind of row was tapped? Do I have other TableViewCells which can be tapped to and I therefore should check against?

Comment: As stated, everything works, except getting callbacks from my actionsheet, which means my tableview works fine. But you said a key thing, which i asked for, if a uitableviewcell should contain this kind of logic, as to which you said it shouldnt. Thank you, i will find an other way

Comment: You're welcome. Try to keep your views 'dumb'. They are responsible for presenting data from models. Controllers are responsible for reflecting changes forth and back. :)

Comment: This is kind of bs, the view CONTROLLER should be kept skinny and the VIEW should implement all VIEW functionality so that the IT is reuseable.

Comment: If I do it your way in a social app then I have to copy methods multiple types for alll the various ways i displays statuses, ideally i should be able to implement something that uses statuses and BOOM it comes with all the statuses functionality.